# Python while loop not updating

Tags: python, bash

I'm very new to Python.

I'm trying to display the current temperature from a sensor, which I get from a bash script. I use `sed` to replace the string in the python script (`temp.py`), which prints that string to an LCD Display.

Unfortunately, when I run `temp.py`, it only shows the temperature it has at the moment I run it, but it will not update, even though the `lcd.py` script is constantly changing (it only shows one temperature).

```
while True:
    lcd_string("Temp: 25.123 *C",LCD_LINE_1,1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

25.123 is changing constantly in `temp.py`, but not the different temperatures are not shown in the LCD

Is there any way to get it to update?

Comment: I assume that everything in the while loop is indented?

Comment: what makes you think 25.123 is always changing?

Comment: @JoranBeasley he is changing it with a _sed_ command

Comment: @Ramirous, I really suggest you another aproach.. It wont work because unless you adit the script the last one was executed with a fixed text end is still running eith the .pyc bytecode

Comment: It is indented, sorry I didn't show it as is. 
I have a temp. sensor, I can see the temperature changing (cold water to hot water), and I see `25.123` changing constantly in `temp.py` due to the instruction given by `sed` from another script

Comment: You could use the 'subprocess' module from your python script to run the bash script and collect the output.  You would then pass said output to a function that updates the lcd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have your sed script constantly update a file called `"label.txt"` (you probably dont even need `sed` ... as an aside, why arent you just interfacing the sensor from python?)

then in your temp.py script

```
while True:
    lcd_string(open("label.txt").read(),LCD_LINE_1,1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

that is probably the easiest way to just make it work ... (See ned's answer as to why your original implementation did not work)

Answer (score 5):

Changing the .py file on disk won't change the running program.  The .py file is only read once, when the program starts.  After that, the .py file isn't used again until the program is run again.

Answer (score 1):

The *.py* file generates a bytecode to run. See the *.pyc* file beside your *temp.py*. So, once the script is running it won't load your change (the one made with *sed* command) in *temp.py* until you run it again.

I really suggest you another approach where you don't use an infinite loop but a single script that takes an argument every time it is executed and send the value to _lcd_string_ method.

Something like:

```
import sys

temp = sys.argv[1]
lcd_string("Temp: %s *C" % temp,LCD_LINE_1,1)
```

and instead of *sed* you can run:

```
python temp.py <your temperature>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bad idea is to reload lcd.py every iteration, the newly value updated by sed will works after saving(the lcd.py file). The code as follows,

```
while True:
    reload(lcd)  # <-------- 
    lcd_string("Temp: 25.123 *C",LCD_LINE_1,1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Note it is not recommended in practice.

Comment: im pretty sure this is running in lcd.py ... can you reload the script that you are in like this? Ive never seen this done... (I know you can reload imported modules like this)